# JQuery UI Selectable - delay the lasso (selection rectangle)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

1. When you just click on a selected element holding ctrl, it will be deselected.
2. Elements "caught" with a lasso (selection rectangle) however, while holding ctrl, are added to the selection. (instead of a XOR mode one might expect)

Now if you desire 1. to happen, but  accidentally move the mouse a little, a lasso will be created and 2. happens - net effect: nothing.
This is irritating, especially when the selectable elements are rather big and the gui isn't perfectly responsive.

I can imagine two approaches to avoid this, namely

- the mentioned XOR mode
- a minimal distance before the lasso starts

I'm open to any approach (also new ones), as long as it comes with an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [delay](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-delay) and [distance](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-distance) options of selectables to avoid triggering selection by unwanted small mouse movements.

> **Delay**:
>
> Time in milliseconds to define when the selecting should start. This helps prevent unwanted selections when clicking on an element.
>
> **Distance**:
>
> Tolerance, in pixels, for when selecting should start. If specified, selecting will not start until the mouse has been dragged beyond the specified distance.

For example:

```js
$("#selectable").selectable({
  delay: 30,
  distance: 30
});
```

```css
#selectable {
  list-style: none;
}
#selectable li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
#selectable .ui-selectee {
  background: #ccc;
}
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="selectable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I had seen the "distance" option before, but somehow I overlooked it 5 times in the api-doc.
But with the distance-option the selection on simple click does not work anymore.